# React: Can you use an argument name to change the state of the same name?

Tags: reactjs, toggle, state, setstate

I have many duplicate this.setState statements doing the same thing of toggling its state, so I was wondering if a general toggle is possible. I know this code doesn't work, and I think I'm not calling the global state correctly. Maybe that's the more detailed question I'm trying to figure out:

```
onToggleState => (state) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    state: prevState.state
  }));
}
```

Comment: `[state]: prevState.state` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer look at computed property names

Comment: Wow what a rookie syntax mistake. It's so clear and indisputably correct once you see it.

Comment: Doesn't feel like a mistake to me. You just didn't know that syntax was available. Now you do.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help.

```js
onToggleState => (state) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    [state]: !prevState[state]
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not recommended to do it, it's better to have setState method for each state in stateful components
by the way, here is an example

```
handleSetState(key, value){
    this.setState({
        [key]: value,
    });
}
```

an example of using it:

```
this.handleSetState('foo', 'bar'); // equivalent of this.setState({foo: 'bar'});
```

it will put 'bar' as value of an state called 'foo'

but as I sade, it's not a good way to handle it, that's why we have hooks in react

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(null);
const [bar, setBar] = useState(null);

setFoo('foo');
setBar('bar');
```